# Printer Installing and using problem on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I am very new to ubuntu 16.04 to use. I was using windows since 2000 and mostly use graphic designing software of adobe. Now I am enjoying scribus 1.5.2 and inkscape 0.91 likewise I and very interesting with libra office writer. I have faced many problem but solved with the help of internet but installing printer makes me quite frustrating. I am not able to install my canon imageclass mf4412 printer that why requested you all for the help.
Atamilo

Comment: what are the issues your facing.

Comment: Have you tried using `cups` to connect your printer ?